# Access a class file from another class file

Tags: java, swing, class

I have three class files, one has a public static void main (String args []) method in it and the other two do not. The one with the main method calls for the first class file in it's main method.

```
public class IonsTest
{   
    public static void main (String args [])
    {
        new IronTest();
    }
}
```

This works, it opens the IronTest class file and that file runs perfectly. The problem now, is trying to get this class file to open the next one. I am trying to have the next class file run when the user clicks a button.

```
if(e.getSource() == next1)
{
    if(ansFe2 && ansFe3 && ansFerrous && ansFerric && ansIronII && ansIronIII == true)
    {
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Good job, let's continue.", "Next", 0);
        CopperTest();
    }
    else
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You must get all answers correct before procceding.");
    }
}
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Should you be doing `new CopperTest()` then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you want to create a new object for your second class and call its constructor like you did for your first class `new IronTest();`.

And if The name of your Second class is `CopperTest` then the call `CopperTest()` is not doing anything. To create a new object of your second class and get its constructor called you need to do the following,

`new CopperTest();`

Comment: Wow, I'm stupid. As you can see I'm pretty new to Java, but thanks, this worked.

Comment: If something works for you then you should accept that answer to let others know what worked for you. To accept an answer you can click on the right tick sign on the left side of the answer which you want to accept. And welcome ! Happy Learning... :)